# Push messages from Azure worker role to asp.net web page hosted in web role

Tags: jquery, asp.net, azure

I need help about my azure project.

I have one worker and one web role. In worker role I have TCP listener
that accept connections in Run() method. Every time connection is accepted
I create new thread that handles accepted client. I send data from IOT device. 
6 bytes every 1100ms. I have two integer value from those 6 bytes.

In web role I host asp.net web page with two asp. net chart and button start.
I need to add those integer values periodically so that I have trend and client can see change in real time.
First I implement data transaction between roles using azure queue, put message in queue in worker role and read it in web role.

I put my chart in update panel and set timer to refresh it every 1s.
I enable timer with click on start button.
In timer event i read message from queue, process it and delete it.
Later I realize this scenario is bad because what if I have two client watching at web page from different computers(one delete message and others can't see it). Second problem is that I only want to show last 2 min of trend(100 message apr.), I cannot guarantee that I will have 100 message in queue and because azure queue is FIFO I could read old data.

More legitime situation is that I push messages from worker role every time i have one ready for transmitting and on client side manage to have only 100 points oh chart. Or I could code long pulling so that client periodically fetch message from server. I was reading about signalR for first solution an classic ajax jquery for second.

I am not sure am I on the right path to solve this problem? Is it possible for worker role to push data to all client using signalR, or can I implement jquery in web role. I am little bit confused can this work in way I planed, or my concept is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you should use signalr.

signalr consists of two parts: 1. many signalr clients.  2. one signalr server.

signalr client can be a simple html or .aspx files with JavaScript function defined.

signalr Server can be a console or winform or service.

the signalr Server can also call any internal/external dll, webservices, webapi, whatever.

if there is any new data in the signalr server, the Server can call clients' JavaScript function to update the clients' page content, so you don't have to use timer in clients to retrieve data from server every second.

you may also store the whole set of latest data in the Server so that when there is a new client connected, the client can get the latest data immediately.